# C# function to distribute weight in a list of numbers

Tags: c#

I have a list of numbers that is something like this.

| Name | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Val 1 | 500 |
| Val 2 | 600 |
| Val 3 | 350 |
| Val 4 | 500 |
| Val 5 | 450 |
| Val 6 | 600 |

Sum of all Amount(s) is 3000 which will remain constant.

The problem I am trying to solve is if I remove one or more rows, amount in remaining rows should increase proportionally so that the sum of Amount(s) of all remaining rows should be 3000.

Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to code this in C#.

Comment: Do you know what algorithm to use _outside of programming_? If you know how to solve this with paper and pencil, translating it to code is much easier.

Comment: That's the problem. I am not able to solve this on paper.

Comment: I don't see why people are voting to close, I was able to answer this easily based on the information provided. You might say that this isn't something that can be answered in code, but my answer does contain important parts of the code he will need.

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Abhigyan - glad you are here :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several options, but this seems straightforward:

- When removing a row, store the removed quantity in a variable. Let's call it `removedAmount`.
- After removing the row, create an array (or some other data structure) to store what percentage of the remaining total each row represents. This will be something like: `row.percent = (rowAmount / totalAmount);`
- Loop through the remaining rows and add `(removedAmount * percent)` to each of them.

There may be some edge cases, particularly if rounding is involved at any step, which could cause your total to end up as an amount that is slightly different from 3000. If this turns out to be the case, there is probably a mathematically perfect way to solve it, however... You could add a step where you detect this difference and remove it proportionally using those same percentages. It would force you to end up at 3000 to matter what, and it should be "pretty good" depending on what you're doing.

Seems workable.

Comment: Thank you for welcoming me Brian. I did that precisely before posting it here. In this example, I had a difference of roughly 83 points which is significant. For example if I remove the first row, the remaining rows will have new values as 700
408.3333333
583.3333333
525
700

The total comes to 2917 after rounding off. A point here or there will be acceptable but not 83 points difference.

Comment: @AbhigyanSrivastava I think you have to calculate percentages after you remove the value for array.

Comment: Rookie mistake. Let me try that. And it is perfect.

Comment: @Brian Mackay - Thank you. This works perfectly. Let me try on few more random lists. I have been banging my head for past one month on this.

Comment: @AbhigyanSrivastava So glad to hear that! And thanks to Jaood for explaining that point about the order of the steps, that was exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the same solution logic as Brian.
So if someone in future will be curious on this topic I just put my implementation here.

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] arr = {500,600,350,500,450,600};
        List<double> list = arr.ToList();
        
        PrintList(list);
        
        //get value of first element
        double removed = list.ElementAt(0);
        //remove first element
        list.RemoveAt(0);
        
        //calculate percentage distribution of all other elements
        List<double> perc = CalcPercentages(list);
        
        //add some portion of deleted value to each remaining element
        List<double> newList = list.Select( (x,i) => x + removed * perc[i]).ToList();
        
        PrintList(newList);
        
    }
    public static List<double> CalcPercentages(List<double> arr){
        double sum = arr.Sum();
        return arr.Select(x=> x / sum).ToList();
    }
    public static void PrintList(List<double> arr){
        string arrayToDisplay = String.Join(", ",arr);
        Console.WriteLine(arrayToDisplay);
    }
}
```

Here is a [link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pr0Oo6) to c# fiddle to play with this code